# What are the risk with creating a collection that does not implement ERC721 Enumerable extension?

Tags: erc-721, opensea

Why most NFT contracts use the **ERC721 Enumerable** extension and not the **ERC721 Metadata** extension (plus a custom `totalSupply()` in case the creators want to list the collection on OpenSea)? I understand enumerables makes it easy to implement and show NFTs on the website of the collection, but is there any other usage I am missing? For example, does Etherscan, or Metamask, rely on the enumerable extension to show NFTs in the wallet? It seems that OpenSea rather listens to the blockchain than relies on availability of asset enumeration functions (it does require `totalSupply()` though). Is there any obvious blockers to creating a collection not implementing **Enumerable**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your risk in using a non-`ERC721Enumerable` contract is as follows:

- If you only use websites like Twitter, OpenSea and MetaMask to access your NFTs and OpenSea and other commercially available centralized API go offline then effectively your NFTs are "gone". You will lose all functionality (i.e. "utility") of using your NFTs because these products all use a centralized API to access your NFT ownership information.
- If you continue to use non-`ERC721Enumerable` contracts, new app developers that cannot be bothered to properly parse the blockchain will be incentivized to use centralized APIs, contributing to the agency risk.

---

In other words, there is no immediate risk to you by using non-`ERC721Enumerable` products. But they are slowing down the "decentralized future".

Comment: Hello and thanks for your answer. So in a nutshell **ERC721Enumerable** provides easy accessibility, since token Id could be generated in a non-sequential way, correct? But if your NFT is generating token ids in a sequential way, then `tokenByIndex` and `tokenOfOwnerByIndex` become useless since you can traverse from **i** to **totalSupply** ( you will need just `totalSupply()`), right?

Comment: I don't traverse on blockchain :-) CryptoKitties tried that and that function broke after they got popular.